# Konqueror empty configuration

Tags: kubuntu, kde, konqueror

I'd like to use Konqueror because I found a comparison between different file managers that stated that Konqueror one of the most customizable file managers. However, in my case the configuration or extensions modal is almost empty. When I start Konqueror using the CLI, I see these error messages:

> org.kde.konqueror: Unable to load the "File Management" configuration
>   module org.kde.konqueror: Unable to load the "Web Browsing"
>   configuration module

Unfortunately, I can't find anything related to this error message.

I installed Konqueror using `apt install konqueror`, which installed version `5.0.97`. I'm using Kubuntu 18.10 with Plasma 5.13.5.

Any idea how I can configure Konqueror? Why are those modals (almost) empty?

Screenshots:

[image: No configuration]
[image: No extensions]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Suggested**

The Konqueror package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/konqueror

is suggesting package: konq-plugins - https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/konq-plugins

> plugins for Konqueror, the KDE file/web/document browser

Plugins will enable lot of options:

[image]
[image]